Why have you come up with the idea of banning someone from posting?
I would like to know the basis of this development.
I believe the platform helps those needing assistance with the challenges they are facing.
The platform has helped me a lot in learning some of the stuff I don't know, and in return, I noted that some have also learned something from my questions. I have asked a few, and from the questions I have asked, only two were not properly constructed, but they did help others.
My suggestion is to create two platforms: one for those who feel like it is a waste to read some of the questions asked by upcoming professionals and those who think they have very adequate knowledge and do not want to share, and one for those seeking assistance because they are having challenges in completing certain tasks.
I believe this is an inclusive platform, and it's just unfortunate that this new management team has come up with this arrangement.

This isn't a new thing, users losing the ability to ask as often after asking several poorly received questions has existed for more than 10 years.

i have been here for years and not days so why now?

it counts everything, including deleted posts, and doesn't seem to care how old something is.

You've asked 10 questions over the years, of which 4 are negatively-scored and 3 are zero-scored. 40% of your questions being poorly received is not great, and 70% of your questions being perceived as not offering any value to the knowledge base is worse. As has been noted, this isn't new.

"Why have you come up with the idea of banning someone from posting?" Because some people make really bad posts and that's generally considered to be a thing we'd like to prevent.

I get it, Kevin, it just time it okay with me

The whole point of [so] is to be a repository of knowledge, and everything is licenced under CC-by-SA, a place where people don't want to share would never be welcome here; the whole point of the site is a place to share knowledge, not hide it.

"I believe the platform helps those needing assistance with the challenges they are facing." the website is a repository of knowledge. Asking questions should be so that other people than you won't have to ask the same question. If you believe it's a help desk, then that means you aren't even treating the platform as its purpose. It should not be surprising then that the system limits you from trying to further mistreat it.

Noted Thom that is an excellent point. thanks

I think I am very fine with what Thom A has pointedd out

Instead of asking the community to change you should asking for feedback on how you can meet the community’s expectations

"I would like to know the basis of this development." Aside from common sense? Every community excludes people, and must do so to survive (though in my experience, the ones claiming "inclusivity" the loudest are often the ones most likely to do it unnecessarily). "and it's just unfortunate that this new management team has come up with this arrangement." To be unfortunate, it would have to be true. Stack Overflow has worked this way since 2010 - so it wasn't strictly always that way, but it was Jeff Atwood's idea and implementation.

I think it is not ideal to argue more on this subject, mind you we come from different regions and most importantly not all of us English is our first language, but we try to make our points clear. This is a very good platform and of course, every platform is guided by rules but how do you assess the abuse, one can make an entry that might be deemed to others as abuse depending on the receipt understanding of the entry. secondly at what interval is one allowed to make a mistake we are all humans we are prone to mistakes. Lastly, inclusiveness is the way  and is the key point to be considered

@PhillipChirazo - Your questions not being well received and you receiving downvotes is not a form of abuse. As been already stated, a question ban is only possible after several poorly received questions, and even after a question ban your not prevented from asking future questions. You are just limited to one question every 6 months

Do you  know the paradox of tolerance? To be tolerant you have to exclude the intolerant, in this case to be inclusive, you have to exclude the ones abusing the system, the ones not being inclusive.

The asker of questions not suited to being added to Stack Overflow's library of questions probably doesn't have abuse of the system on their mind, but after several such questions with no sign of improvement, is there a logical reason to continue to allow their participation? What Stack Overflow really needs is much more accessible documentation on what is and isn't accepted and some way to force askers to read the documentation. Since the second requirement is not practical to enforce, the best way to force folks to the the required reading seems to be to ban them.

The reason Stack Overflow is successful is because of its high quality questions and answers, and the reason for that quality is its strict quality standards. Ask yourself why you came here instead of some other place like Reddit or whatever that allows any question?

@user4581301 - All information does exist.  However, I have never seen a user NOT ask multiple low quality questions in a row, read that material before creating a problem for themselves.  They do not even pause for us to react to the number of questions, at times some users, submit dozens of questions in a timeframe of minutes.

As I said multiple times, I agree with Thom A's response. Let me also acknowledge contributions by @user458130 and Security Hound. Your points are well-noted, and reading documentation must indeed be enforced somehow. And then once you note that one has posted low-quality questions inform that particular user that your time to ask a question has expired till such a period. I think it is better to contribute positively to all the questions you can't contribute with a  negative response, I am here because this a good platform, and in regards to tolerance Security Hound has responded well
